# Как убрать открытие балуна организаций в yandex-map?

Tags: яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

При работе с ynadex map api на react, я не нашёл способа убрать вот эту плашку при нажатии на любую организацию. В идеале бы её вообще не открывать. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

map.current.balloon.destroy();

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Вам следует отключить интерактивность POI на карте.
В JS API за это отвечает опция карты **[yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map.html#Map__param-options.yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity)**, которую необходимо включить.

В React Yandex Maps эта опция должна включаться также, как и все прочие:

```
<YMaps>
  <Map defaultState={{ center: [55.751574, 37.573856], zoom: 9 }}
     options={{
        yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity: true
      }}
    />
</YMaps>
```